# Install GWT Designer plug-in in Eclipse Indigo from JAR

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-indigo, gwt-designer

I got the following error while trying to install GWT Designer via Eclipse Indigo -> Install new software

Progress was made upto 37% and then it terminatedw with the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.doc.user_2.4.2.r37x201110181249.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user_1.2.0.r37x201109270322.jar.
```

GWT , GAE SDKs and plugins have been successfully installed though. ( and is running too)

I downloaded the JAR file from :

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.doc.user_2.4.2.r37x201110181249.jar

Now Where do I add this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error typically means that you had a local communication failure. Wait a few minutes, restart Eclipse and try it again.